# Android, using SimpleCursorAdapter to set colour not just strings

Tags: android, listview, simplecursoradapter

I have a simple cursor adapter set on a list in my application as follows:

```
private static final String fields[] = {"GenreLabel", "Colour", BaseColumns._ID};


datasource = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row, data, fields, new int[]{R.id.genreBox, R.id.colourBox});
```

R.layout.row consists of two TextViews (genreBox and colourBox). Rather than setting the content of the TextView to the value of "Colour" , I would like to set its background colour to that value.

What would I need to do to achieve this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Check out [SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder.html).

[setViewValue](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder.html#setViewValue%28android.view.View,%20android.database.Cursor,%20int%29) is basically your chance to do whatever you wish with the data in your `Cursor`, including setting the background color of your views.

For example, something like:

```
SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder binder = new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {
    @Override
    public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
        String name = cursor.getColumnName(columnIndex);
        if ("Colour".equals(name)) {
            int color = cursor.getInt(columnIndex);
            view.setBackgroundColor(color);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
datasource.setViewBinder(binder);
```

**Update** - if you're using a custom adapter (extending `CursorAdaptor`) then the code doesn't change a whole lot. You'd be overriding `getView` and `bindView`:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView != null) {
        return convertView;
    }
    /* context is the outer activity or a context saved in the constructor */
    return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.id.my_row);
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    int color = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("Colour"));
    view.setBackgroundColor(color);
    String label = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("GenreLabel"));
    TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.genre_label);
    text.setText(label);
}
```

You're doing a bit more manually, but it's more or less the same idea. Note that in all of these examples you might save on performance by caching the column indices instead of looking them up via strings.

Comment: Thank you, this did exactly what I needed and very simply too.

Comment: Great! I have always used custom adapters, but often what you need can be done simply with ViewBinder.

Comment: Is there any chance you could also provide an example of the custom adapter method of doing this? Eventually I will have a whole load of adapters in my app and i think extending the simplecursoradapter might be the best way in the long run.

Comment: Added some code. Note that you probably want to extend `CursorAdapter` and not `SimpleCursorAdapter`.

Comment: Thanks, the second method looks more scalable to what I want to do eventually. And thanks for the note about CursorAdapter vs SimpleCursorAdapter.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for requires a custom cursor adapter.  You can subclass [SimpleCursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html).  This basically give access to the view as its created (although you'll be creating it yourself).

See this [blog post](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/11/custom-cursoradapters/) on custom CursorAdapters for a complete example.  Particularly, I think you'll need to override `bindView`.